# select current row from table with id from page url

Tags: php, mysql

I made a link [example.com/post.php?pid=3](http://example.com/post.php?pid=3) on my index page to view information from table with id that specified on that url. How to get the id value from page url?
I have try to use this.

```
if($_GET['id']){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $sql="SELECT * FROM tableName where id='$id'";
   $data = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
   echo $row['post_title'];
```

but is doesn't give any result. Do you have a better idea?

Then I update my code like this
to get the pid value

```
$pid = isset($_GET['pid']) ? intval($_GET['pid']) : 0;
```

this code succesfully get the pid value from the url, when I confirm by `echo $pid;`

And then I use this code to fetch data from my table

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$db->prefix.'tableName WHERE id='.$pid) or error('failed', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
```

but it doesn't give any result when I confirm it by `echo $post_title;`
can you tell me which one is incorrect? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of **$id** you're getting?

Comment: remove mysql and use mysqli or pdo

Comment: Your current code is wide open to sql injection attacks. You want to read and learn about the advantages of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding", which also requires you to port your code from the old, outdated and long since deprecated `mysql_...()` functions to the current `mysqli` extension or the `PDO` package.

Comment: Nice, 3 answers and nobody mention the security lack of SQL injections or the old mysql_* driver. All just want their reputation. Just sad that nobody takes time to mention those things. For OP: take a look at http://bobby-tables.com - learn something about SQL injection and use mysqli_ or PDO_ drivers. mysql_ is deprecated and not longer supoorted in PHP7+. @arkascha Thanks!!! At least one guy!

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: @LarasatiHabibi you have answers below

Answer (score 3):

Change it:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

to

```
$id = $_GET['pid'];
```

because the index is `pid=3` and you are trying to get its value by `id`

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Print the query and run it on database terminal and check what happens

Answer (score 1):

> You have about 5 answers before mine and and all the answers have
>   shown you your mistakes, and they are correct they have also suggested
>   that you stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are depreciated and no
>   longer supported, better use mysqli or pdo prepared statements.

But none of those answers have shown you where to learn that or answered you using mysqli.

also none of them told you that there's no need to `select *` when you only gonna want one row, as your query shows.

> In fact  you should Never SELECT * in a production environment, it
>   will only come back to bite you in weird, unpredictable and seemingly
>   unrelated ways. By specifying the columns you want, you will ensure
>   that column ordering, data-type, constraint and all sorts of other
>   elements won't cause you problems in the long run.

I have taken sometime to give you an answer using the apis suggested above, **mysqli and pdo with prepared statements**

**mysqli :**

```
<?
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//check if pid is set and not empty
if (isset($_GET['pid']) && !empty($_GET['pid'])) {

    $id = intval($_GET['pid']);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT post_title FROM tableName WHERE id = ?  ");
    $sql->bind_param('i', $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($post_title);

    while ($sql->fetch()) {

        echo $post_title;
    }

} else {

    //return errors
}



?>
```

**PDO**

```
 <?php


$host    = 'YOURHOST';
$db      = 'YOURDB';
$user    = 'YOURUSERNAME';
$pass    = 'YOURPASSWORD';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];


$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);



if (isset($_GET['pid']) && !empty($_GET['pid'])) {

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT post_title FROM tableName WHERE id = ?");
    $sql->execute([$id]);
    $row = $sql->fetch();

    echo $row['post_title'];


} else {

    //return something
}

?>
```

Resources you can learn from :

**mysqli prepared :**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_prepare.htm
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

**PDO :**

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Answer (score 0):

Update code to: change

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

to

```
$id = $_GET['pid']
```

because `example.com/post.php?pid=3` in this url `pid` is get value so use `pid` in your code

remove mysql and use pdo or mysqli

for more information
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: SELECT * FROM '.$db->prefix.'tableName WHERE id='.$pid ? which your table name?

Comment: tableName is my table name

Comment: if table name is tableName then 

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='.$pid
and for test echo SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='.$pid;
and run this in phpmyadmin

Comment: echo SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='.$pid; 

and run in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you code print `id` and in url you pass `pid`

```
$id = $_GET['pid'];
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: so please accept the ans and please give upvote to ans

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code

```
if($_GET['pid']){ // You are passing `pid` in your request
   $id = $_GET['pid'];
   $sql="SELECT * FROM tableName where id='" . $id . "'"; // $id is the variable
   $data = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
   echo $row['post_title'];
```

This code is not secure. As well as PHP 7 deprecated the `mysql` extension. Instead use Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: @LarasatiHabibi Can you please post some more code of new query??

Comment: I have posted it on my question(it has been updated with my new query), please take a look,

Comment: @LarasatiHabibi Did you fetch the data using `$db->fetch_assoc()` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to check if variable exist use an isset() function.
In your url you have created a variable with the name of "pid"
therefore,

```
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
       $id = $_GET['pid'];
       $sql="SELECT * FROM tableName where id='$id'";
       $data = mysql_query($sql);
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
       echo $row['post_title'];
}
```

But please note that..!! mysql_* functions have been deprecated. You must learn mysqli_  or PDO.

Comment: Hi I have updated my code, could you please take a look and give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance